# How do I write a query to return a string concatenated with the greatest number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.5.25 on Mac 10.7.5.  I have a number of usernames in my database table of the form

```
prefix
prefix1
prefix2
prefix3
```

I would like to write a query that returns the username with the highest number after the prefix.  For example, in the above list, the query would return "prefix3".  Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: You could start by looking into the [string functions you have available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: Do you need them ordered lexicographically or numerically? I.e. if they're prefix100 and prefix2, which do you want chosen as the highest?

Comment: @PatrickEvans The number is already concatenated, he doesn't need to call `CONCAT`.

Comment: @Barmar ah, i thought he was showing a sample of what he wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT username FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY convert(REPLACE(username, 'prefix', ''), signed) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Make sure to put the correct PREFIX, USERNAME column name as well as the correct TABLE name.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them alphabetically, descending.  The top result will be the highest number, provided they're formatted in a consistent way.